# Is $O_{D}(X)$ a reflective Banach space?

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface and $O_{X}(D)$ be the line bundle associated with $D$. Let the metric on $O_{X}(D)$ be given by 
$$
|1_{O_{X}(D)}(P)|=G(P,D)^2
$$
where $G(P,D)^2$ is the Green function associated with $D$ and $P$ which vanishes up to first order on the diagonal.

My question is whether $O_{X}(D)$ equipped with this metric is a reflective Banach space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Can you explain what is Green function associated to $P$ and $P$ or some reference?